# Requests: Python Post Request only returns error code 400

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

(I'm new to posting on stack overflow tell me stuff to improve on ty)
I recently got into python requests and I am a bit new to web stuff related to python so if its something stupid don't flame me. I've been trying a lot of ways to get one of my post events to not return error 400. I messed with headers and data and a bunch of other stuff and I would either get code 404 or 400.

I have tried adding a bunch of headers to my project. Im trying to login to the site "Roblox" making a auto purchase bot. The Csrf Token was not in cookies so I found a loop hole getting the token with sending a request to a logout url (If anyone gets confused). I double checked the Data I inputted aswell and it is indeed correct. I was researching for multiple hours and I couldn't find a way to fix so I came to stack overflow for the first time.

```
RobloxSignInDeatils = { 
    "cvalue": "TestWebDevAcc", #Username
    "ctype": "Username", #Leave Alone
    "password": "Test123123" #Password
}

def GetToken(Session, Headers):
    LogoutUrl = "https://api.roblox.com/sign-out/v1" #Url to get CSRF
    Request = Session.post(LogoutUrl, Headers) #Sent Post
    print("Token: ", Request.headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"]) #Steal the token
    return Request.headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] #Return Token

with requests.session() as CurrentSession:
    Header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36"
    } #Get the UserAgent Header Only
    CurrentSession.get("https://www.roblox.com/login", headers=Header) #Send to the login page
    CsrfToken = GetToken(CurrentSession, Header) #Get The Token

    Header["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = CsrfToken #Set the token
    SignIn = CurrentSession.post("https://auth.roblox.com/v2/login",
                                 data=RobloxSignInDeatils, headers=Header) # Send Post to Sign in
    print(SignIn.status_code) #Returns 400 ?
```

Printing "print(SignIn.status_code)" just returns 400 nothing else to explain

EDIT: If this helps heres a list of ALL the headers:

```
Request URL: https://auth.roblox.com/v2/login
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 128.116.112.44:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-CSRF-TOKEN,Content-Type,Pragma,Cache-Control,Expires
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.roblox.com
Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
Cache-Control: max-age=120, private
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 14 Feb 2019 04:04:13 GMT
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE"
Roblox-Machine-Id: CHI1-WEB2875
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-csrf-token
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: auth.roblox.com
Origin: https://www.roblox.com
Referer: https://www.roblox.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.96 Safari/537.36
Payload:
{cvalue: "TestWebDevAcc", ctype: "Username", password: "Test123123"}
```

Comment: Have you tried using something like postman to try and run the request manually first?

Comment: Im sorry im not familiar to "postman" ?

Comment: Google it - it's a UI for making HTTP requests

Comment: Wow this makes my life so much more easier, ill get straight to downloading/researching if I do find the issue ill make sure to answer myself.